# Extract unique values from column based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, unique, criteria

I would like to extract unique values based on a criteria. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim objdict As Object
    Dim lngrow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set objdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        x = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)))
        For lngrow = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            objdict(x(lngrow)) = 1
        Next
        .Range("C1:C" & objdict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objdict.keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

Below what I would like to achieve:

[image: img]

As you can see the values are in column A, the criteria are in column B and the unique values are in column C. Can anyone show me what I need to change in my code?

Comment: What problem is your code giving you?

Comment: Which criteria?  i don't understand what you're trying to achieve, or where you're stuck.  It seems like you could just use `COUNTIF` or `Remove Duplicates`.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that, unique keys are mandatory.  What are your keys becoming in that scenario? Seems like it could be done without dictionary, unless you use a "does this key exist?" feature of dictionary and allow it to actually help you, you can code it so if you try to create a key that exists nothing happens, it doesn't get added to the dictionary, that is how you want to use dictionary to filter unique.

Comment: @ashleedawg I believe the OP wants to use keys to identify unique sets of values, there are examples here on SO of doing that, if a key already exists then ignore the add, or catch the error on add and keep going.  Using "keys" as a unique value set really, linked to any number of other records of course.  Looks like a "unique key" and a value of 1 meets his criteria.  Seems like easier ways to do this unless there are a pile of value criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! See the comments in the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim objDict As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long

    Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheet1 '<== You can directly use the (Name) property of the worksheet as seen from the VBA editor.
        x = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(XlDirection.xlUp)).Value

        For lngRow = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            If x(lngRow, 2) = 1 Then '<== Example criteria: value is 1 in column B.
                objDict(x(lngRow, 1)) = 1 '<== Don't know if this is significant in your case (I typically assign True).
            End If
        Next

        .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(objDict.Count, 3)).Value = Application.Transpose(objDict.Keys)
    End With

    'Cleanup.
    Set objDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that I've replaced the strings used within `Range()` by the numeric indices (row, column), which IMHO is better practice.